# Couldn't retrieve teams from graph api - GetThreadS2SRequest Not found

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a global administrator account who consented to have access to microsoft teams.
Then using graph api https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team').
It returned the list of groups for this tenant.
However, when I called [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/%7Bid%7D). Some of the ids worked but some of them returned "error": {
"code": "NotFound",
"message": "Failed to execute Skype backend request GetThreadS2SRequest.",
"innerError": {
"date": "2021-05-17T06:04:19",
"request-id": "02f0a689-eca6-4b0d-9f0f-9d3e876d8f08",
"client-request-id": "02f0a689-eca6-4b0d-9f0f-9d3e876d8f08"
}
}

In addition, I used [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7Bid%7D) and it returned the group information correctly.

So why graph api returned NotFound while it is a valid team group?

Thanks,
Karen

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is some confusion around teams and groups.

Not all groups have a team. Any group that has a team has a **resourceProvisioningOptions** property that contains "Team".

Please note that the group has the same ID as the team. Every team is associated with a group but not vice-versa. When you get NOTFound, this is because that group doesn't have a team associated so accessing [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/%7Bid%7D) will give you 404.

Thus,
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/team](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7Bid%7D/team) is the same as [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%7Bid%7D).

Please refer to the Teams and groups section in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) to understand better.

Comment: Thanks Shweta for your response.

Sorry, the filter should be by resourceProvisioningOptions not displayName. I edited the orginal question. The groups have been filtered by ?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')

Comment: @KarenCu - When you use the filter query parameter you need to use operators as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: @KarenCu I am not able to reproduce this issue at my end. Could you please try again and confirm if it is still happening with you?